# How can I print source line number in Perl?

Tags: perl, line-numbers

Is it possible to get the current source line number in Perl?
The equivalent in C++ is `__LINE__`.

Comment: I'm wondering though: why would you need this?

Comment: I've used it to quickly track the progress through a very long process, and to check the order things are done in, like breakpoints but without using the debugger

Comment: @LeonTimmermans: I am responding to your very old comment about why a Perl programmer might want _ _FILE_ _ and _ _ LINE _ _.  Basically, the same reasons why a C/C++ programmer might want them.  E.g. today I refactored a test so that Test::Differences::eq_or_diff was called in a subroutine. The line number reported was in the subroutine not where the subroutine was called from. Adding __ LINE __ to the test name helps me find the failing test.  Now if I could just write a macro CODE_LOCATION in Perl5.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The `__LINE__` literal is documented in the [Special Literals](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Special-Literals) section of the [perldata man page](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata).

```
print "File: ", __FILE__, " Line: ", __LINE__, "\n";
```

or

```
warn("foo");
```

Comment: Maybe I do bad google searches, though in 99.999% they are very precise for me. For this question I search with a sentence 'how to print current line in perl' basically, and I got only replies regards outputting the line number from the file read with  `$.`, which is trivial as incrementing variable in a loop reading lines. So I wonder if many other people would not have the same issue. Interestingly enough, it seems as if Google put this question among search results once I searched for it differently, or I just overlooked it at my initial attempts.

Answer (score 8):

Note there's a gotcha with

```
$ perl -e'warn("foo")'
foo at -e line 1.
```

If it ends with a newline it *won't* print the line number

```
$ perl -e'warn("foo\n")'
foo
```

This is documented in `perldoc -f die`, but is perhaps easy to miss in the `perldoc -f warn` section's reference to `die`.

Answer (score 2):

This prints out the line where you are, and also the "stack" (list of lines from the calling programs (scripts/modules/etc) that lead to the place you are now)

```
while(my @where=caller($frame++)) { print "$frame:" . join(",",@where) . "\n"; }
```

Answer (score 2):

"use Carp" and play with the various routines and you also get a stack - not sure if this way is better or worse than the "caller" method suggested by cnd.  I have used the LINE and FILE variables (and probably other similar variables) in C and Perl to show where I got in the code and other information when debugging but have seen little value outside a debug environment.